# SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated INNER JOIN on like

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, sql-like

I am running SQL Server 2014 and am trying to perform an `INNER JOIN` on a `LIKE`. The two columns are both `varchar(max)` and I am confident none of the values actually reach the 8000 character limits.

I seem to be getting the error on the line that contains my `LIKE` keyword:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

Query:

```
SELECT  
    OP.Symbol, CL.Counted, CL.NumOfDays, CL.PNLPerc, CL.WLRatio
FROM  
    #ClosedSymbols AS CL 
INNER JOIN 
    #OpenSymbols AS OP ON CL.AllEvents LIKE '%' + OP.AllEvents
```

I'd be happy with a work around but I already tried to do an `EXISTS` with the same result.

Here are my table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE #OpenSymbols(
    [Symbol] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [AllEvents] [varchar] (MAX) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #ClosedSymbols(
    [AllEvents] [VARCHAR] (MAX) NULL,
    [PNLPerc] [money] NULL,
    [WLRatio] [float] NULL,
    [Counted] [int] NULL,
    [NumOfDays] [int] NULL
)
```

Comment: Please add CREATE statement of your tables ;).

Comment: while select you get this error ?

Comment: @shA.t The table structure shouldn't make any difference since it's a SELECT and not an INSERT, but as I said the "AllEvents'' columns are both varchar(max) columns.

Comment: @utility Yes, that's the thing that doesn't make sense.  I'm not adding anything to any tables so there's no reason for this error, but yet there it is.

Comment: does inserting trigger this error ?

Comment: So, Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e51b3/1), or make another one more closer to your structure ;).

Comment: @utility No, there is no insert.  Most of the other results I look for on this error have to do with inserting into a table where the field is not large enough.  I am not doing that at all.  I have no insert going on, just a simple SELECT Query.

Comment: one final thing..just try the same statement with excluding OP.Symbol in your query and tell if same error exist..

Comment: what does this do: `#OpenSymbols AS OP ON 'ABC' LIKE '%' + OP.AllEvents` ? Do you still get the error?

Comment: @utility You hit upon something.  I took OP.Symbol out and the query ran without a problem.

Comment: yes..found out :) you have symbol as varchar(10) change that column datatype to some larger value like varchar(100)..and let me know

Comment: @utility I'm sorry but I screwed up.  I accidentally changed the query back to an on equals when I test your suggestion and I didn't catch it until just now.  It looks like removing OP.Symbol didn't run when using ON LIKE.

Comment: Double check the lengths of the columns involved in the `like` with `len` and `datalength`. The only way I can produce this error is if they exceed 8000 characters after the concatenation http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b040f/3

Comment: By 'didn't run' do you mean you got the same error? That means the issue is in `OP.AllEvents` instead of `CL.AllEvents`. You now have exactly 50% less areas to search for the problem. Now to confirm try this: `#OpenSymbols AS OP ON CL.AllEvents LIKE '%ABC'`

Comment: Then the next step is to add where clauses to narrow the actual records down.

Answer (score 0):

please make sure data type and length of your column because this works for me

```
declare @table1 table
(
col varchar(max)
)
insert into @table1 values ('jay hanuman gyan gun sagar');
declare @table2 table
(
col varchar(max)
)
insert into @table2 values ('gun sagar');


select * from @table1 t1 join @table2 t2
on t1.col like  '%' + t2.col 
--OR
select * from @table1 t1 join @table2 t2
on t1.col like  CONCAT('%', t2.col)
```

UPDATE: after comment

```
declare @table1 table(
    [Symbol] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [AllEvents] [varchar] (MAX) NULL
)

declare @table2 table(
    [AllEvents] [VARCHAR] (MAX) NULL,
    [PNLPerc] [money] NULL,
    [WLRatio] [float] NULL,
    [Counted] [int] NULL,
    [NumOfDays] [int] NULL
)

insert into @table1 (Symbol,AllEvents) values ('kuch b','Incorrect syntax near the keyword');
insert into @table2 (AllEvents) values ('the keyword');


select * from @table1 t1 join @table2 t2
on t1.AllEvents like  '%' + t2.AllEvents
```

Comment: @SteveBishop please check UPDATED

Comment: With your values it works, with the real data it doesn't.

Comment: @SteveBishop please cross check your DB design might something miss there i hope you get solution from there

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The two values being compared in the LIKE are of the same data type.  It's happening on a SELECT query, not even inserting any data into anything and consistently the error message shows the error is on the ON LIKE line.

Comment: if it is working with my values give us your actual value then we can try it OR let me know how can i help you